# How to set identity cache in SQL Server 2014

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to turn identity cache off in SQL Server 2014 - how to that?

I tried the following command

```
ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION 
    SET IDENTITY_CACHE = OFF
```

I am doing so to make the auto increment work without increment by 1000 on restart

Comment: Why does it matter if it skips 1000? An `IDENTITY` is just an arbitrary number; it doesn't matter if the number is 1, 7, 356, or 1356.

Comment: i have a for loop in my python program that updates after every 30 items by id The update query updates by id

Comment: But removing the cache won't stop the values skipping when you have a failed Insert, rollback, etc. So what you're after won't fix the underlying problem, that you're relying on the value of the `IDENTITY` to increment by 1 digit with evert row and reuse values that failed insertion. You should be using `ROW_NUMBER` or `OFFSET` to get "pages" of data.

Comment: Yes - and ? Does this command not work? Do you get an error ? If so: what error?

Comment: The rollback could be one or two times but the difference of 1000 wont be handled

Comment: @RohanAjmani that's a bug in the code's logic then. You *can't* anticipate IDs - what if there are more than 1 concurrent inserts? A database is meant to handle many thousands of concurrent operations. Even if you turn the cache off, you won't be able to match the generated IDs

Comment: Which is why I suggest `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourIdentity)` and the use of a CTE to filter to `WHERE RN BETWEEN 31 and 60` or use `OFFSET`, and do something like `ORDER BY YourIdentity OFFSET 30 ROWS FETCH NEXT 30 ROWS ONLY;`.

Comment: @RohanAjmani `the difference of 1000 wont be handled` why should it be handled? What does the Python code try to do? That's the problem, not the identity cache.

Comment: @RohanAjmani what is the *real* problem you want to solve, and why do you think that tracking the `IDENTITY` on the client is the solution? Why not use a `SEQUENCE`? Or *nothing at all* and just retrieve the new values, eg with an `OUTPUT` clause?

Comment: ok i agree with you OFFSET will work in this case

Comment: The [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info) at it's finest. ;) You can parametrise `OFFSET` too, if you need it. So something like `OFFSET @I ROWS FETCH NEXT 30 ROWS ONLY;` is allowed. If you're calling  from Python, you can therefore control the `OFFSET`'s value programmatically *and* **parametrise** it.